# Can't select ul and li elements in nested list

Tags: jquery, nested, html-lists

I have this code generating by jQuery, and can be n-level of ul and n-list item

```
<ul id="criteria">
<li>
    Goal
    <img id="add_criterion" class="add_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon.png">
    <ul id="1" class="criteria">
        <li id="1">
        criteria 1
            <ul id="2" class="criteria">
                <li id="2"> criteria 1
                    <ul id="3" class="criteria">
                       <li id="3">criteria 1</li>
                       <li id="4">criteria 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="3"> criteria 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="2"> criteria 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove li that corresponding to its id and level, I wrote this function where level is the id of ul and i is the id of li

```
function removeElementLi(i,level){
// if one list item in un order list

if($("ul#criteria ul#"+level+" li").length ==1){
    $("ul#criteria ul#"+level).remove();
}else{
    $("ul#criteria ul#"+level+" li#"+i).remove();
}   
}
```

But it did not work, any help I appreciate it.

I changed the function to

```
if($("ul[id="+level+"][class=criteria] li").length ==1){
    $("ul[id="+level+"][class=criteria]").remove();
}else{
    $("ul[id="+level+"][class=criteria] li#"+i).remove();
}
```

but for this html code

```
 <ul id="criteria">
    <li>Goal
    <img id="add_criterion" class="add_criterion" src="../images/icons/add-icon.png">
        <ul id="1" class="criteria">
            <li id="1">criteria 1</li>
            <li id="2">criteria 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

when I start to remove the second li, it works but when I start to remove the first li it didn't work. I alert the jQuery statement

```
ul[id=1][class=criteria] li#1
```

and the length is 2 in this case

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : ID must be **unique**

and the problem is that you are using the `ul#criteria` it should be `ul.criteria` because the `criteria` is a class

please check the [jquery id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

When you have `multiple elements` with the same id's on the page and use a `ID` selector to select a element the selector engine just selects the first id that comes across .

Try using a `class` instead of `id`